# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k / \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $n > 1$?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, divisibility, problem-solving

Let $ A = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k $ and $ B = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k$, where $n >1 $ is a positive integer.

Is $A/B$ ever an integer?

Comment: When $n$ is odd, $n$ is a factor of $B$, and when $n$ is even, $n+1$ is a factor of $B$.  Perhaps that could help.

Comment: Since $B=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer  Thanks, I've guessed that $ (2n+1) \nmid \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} k^k $, but it turns out wrong  :(

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman  I don't know, just found it in a Chinese BBS and no one solved it.  I use Mathematica to try and it holds for n < 1000

Comment: The problem might be relatively tough. $A$ is discussed in an old AMM problem [4155] and looks like a summation version of the hyperfactorial (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html) but is not something I otherwise recognize. Where is the Chinese site?

Comment: which year? AMM [4155],Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian Wishard, G. W., & Underwood, F. (1946). 4155. *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 53(8), 471-473.

Comment: @easymath3 I've just tested it up to 20,000. No candidate worked.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Here is a Python script with which you can check the first 10,000 numbers within 12 seconds: http://pastebin.com/1TbNxCU3

Comment: I'm quite interested in your problem. Could you please contact me with zhushuierjirou@gmail.com or 13777359367?

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sum n = \frac 1 2 n(n+1)$, and note that $n \mid n^n$ but $n+1 \nmid n^n$. For coprime $a$ and $b$ (nb. $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime):

> $ab \mid n \iff a \mid n \wedge b\mid n$

and

> $a\mid q\times a+r \iff a \mid r$

we can write:

> $\frac {n(n+1)}{2}  \mid \sum_{i=1}^n i^i \iff \{k_{n+1} \mid \sum_{i=1}^n i^i\} \wedge \{k_n \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^i\}$

Where $k_n = \begin{cases} \frac n 2 & n \text{ is even} \\ n & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$

This reduces the problem to working out:

> $\text{When does } k_n \text{ divide } \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^i \text{ ?} \quad*$

I tested every number up to 132,000 (using a script I've appended at the bottom) and the numbers satisfying $n\mid \sum_{i=0}^n i^i$ are:

```
1 
3     =3
7     =7
16    =2*2*2*2
18    =2*3*3
33    =3*11
49    =7*7
147   =3*7*7
161   =7*23
183   =3*61
487   =487
647   =647
1549  =1549
1576  =2*2*2*197
3563  =7*509
4049  =4049
4387  =41*107
5872  =2*2*2*2*367
6638  =2*3319
8578  =2*4289
8805  =3*5*587
9549  =3*3*1061
59453 =59453   
62499 =3*83*251
```

I am interested that these numbers have very few prime factors and I think that it might might be possible to prove that:

- there are infinitely many such numbers
- there are no pairs of such numbers

using a combination of interesting modular arithmetic and some fun prime number manipulation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can go one step further and state that the original question is equivalent to this one: When does $n$ divide $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^i$ for two consecutive values of $n$? (The smaller of the two values is a solution to the original question.)

Comment: Exactly <padding>

Comment: Thanks. It took me longer than it should have to realize that, so I thought it was worth mentioning for others!

Comment: @ali0sha where did $k_n$ come into it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it - I'm trying to emphasise that you can get rid of the factor of 2 by taking into account the parity of n

Comment: The reverse implication in your second sentence is false when a,b are not relatively prime. 6 and 9 each divide 18, but 6*9=54 does not.

Comment: @nate I've edited my answer to note the coprimality of n and n+1